# Does repeating heading text in a span hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, html

For the design I am following, I've had to repeat heading text on a site I am building.

I was wondering how this might affect SEO and if I should invest time in trying to change the markup to only use 1 set of text?

This is the current markup:

```html
<div class="chapter__title">
    <h1>THIS IS THE TITLE</h1>
    <span>THIS IS THE TITLE</span>
</div>
```

Will this affect SEO rankings, and if so is there a way to 'ignore' the repeated title or similar?

Comment: Google will treat it as noise so it won't hurt you nor will it help you.

Comment: It'd be useful to tell us exactly why you feel the need to use both... edit the question and include the CSS for this element.

Comment: @SimonHayter Great thanks Simon. I'm not doing it to help but just want to make sure it doesn't penalize the site for it.

The reason for using both isn't really relative here - the design I've been given basically requires the titles to be split, half one colour and half another. I've made a seperate question for this on the relative SE site. The reason for asking this here is to find whether the solution I've gone for will impact my rankings so I can try find a new solution if it does!

Comment: You can double for cosmetic reasons using `::AFTER` or `::BEFORE`  with `content: 'Your Duplicate Title';` and `position: absolute;` leaving the code clean.